# SQL Server compare two tables rows with identical columns and return changed columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

I want to compare two tables with the same columns:

- `product` - `Id, Name, Description`
- `Temp_Product` - `Id, Name, Description`

Now update done by user will be saved into `Temp_Product`. When admin will see the details of that product I need to show the changes done by user. I want to compare both tables with a query and return columns that have changed from `Product` to `Temp_Product`.

Please suggest me better way to do this?

Comment: Well, in order to suggest a *better way* - we need to see what you already have! [Show us what you have tried yourself](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Which columns remain the same and which can change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select p.id,p.name as orgn,t.name as altn,p.descripion as orgd,t.description as altd
from product p
join tmp_product t
on t.id=p.id and (t.name<>p.name or t.description <> p.description)
```

Comment: how can i make a linq query equivalent of this?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to compare both tables with a query and return columns that
>   have changed from Product to Temp_Product

Since the two tables have the same structure, you can use the [**`EXCEPT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)  set oeprator for this:

```
SELECT * FROM Temp_Product
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Product;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fe98/2)