# Show only fields from table1 different than table2 (Sql server 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008, except

I get a file every day that may or may not have changes from the previous day, I copy the file I receive and call it table2, the next day I receive the file I load it in table1 but now I want to see what's changed.  The problem is, I don't want to see the entire row, I just want to see what has changed.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
([Emp_ID] int, [DOB] date, [code] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
 ([Emp_ID], [DOB], [code])
VALUES
 (55556, '1966-01-15', '5454'),
 (55557, '1980-03-21', '6868'),
 (55558, '1985-04-26', '7979'),
 (55559, '1990-10-17', '1212'),
 (55560, '1992-12-30', '6767')
;
CREATE TABLE Table2
([Emp_ID] int, [DOB] date, [code] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
 ([Emp_ID], [DOB], [code])
VALUES
 (55556, '1966-01-15', '5454'),
 (55557, '1980-03-21', '6868'),
 (55558, '1985-04-26', '7979'),
 (55559, '1990-10-17', '1212'),
 (55560, '1992-12-30', '5555')
;
```

Now if I use the EXCEPT function I will see

```
select * from table1
except
select * from table2

EMP_ID  DOB         CODE
55560   1992-12-30  6767
```

But what If I just want to see the EMP_ID and the field that has changed, so I want to see this result.

```
EMP_ID  DOB         CODE
55560               6767
```

Because the Code is all that has changed for that EMP_ID?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I think it would be easier to export two tables to csv and compare the files. There are a lot of apps that will nicely highlight any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to determine the differences. Then join those results with the initial table, using a [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) expression on each field to determine if the particular field has changed.

```
;with UpdatedRecords as
( select * from table1
  except
  select * from table2
)
select ur.EMP_ID, 
       CASE WHEN ur.DOB <> t2.DOB THEN ur.DOB ELSE NULL END as DOB,
       CASE WHEN ur.code <> t2.code THEN ur.code ELSE NULL END as code

from UpdatedRecords ur
join table2 t2 on ur.EMP_ID=t2.EMP_ID
```

Comment: the CTE would capture the differences but it still would not show me what has changed with a specific EMP though...

Comment: I misunderstood your desired results. I've updated this answer show the results you described- EMPs that have changed and only the changed fields.

Comment: There were some other good options given but this is the way I ended up going, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table1] tb1
WHERE tb1.[EMP_ID] not in (select [EMP_ID] from [Table1])
```

It works for me.

But this example is just for ID comparing. Be carefull

**EDITED**

I just find [one article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_set_to_join_sql_parameter.htm) & I hope it will help you to solve your problem:

**Example:**

```
(select * from A 
 minus
 select * from B) -- Rows in A that are not in B
 union all
  ( 
   select * from B 
   minus
   select * from A
  ) -- rows in B that are not in A
```

Also you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428993/sql-server-compare-two-tables-rows-with-identical-columns-and-return-changed-col)

Comment: Yeah, this would give me all the new IDs which is one part of what I am doing but I still need to find changes for the second part, updating existing records.

Comment: Sorry, I can't test it by myself just now, 'cause It's not my comp :)

Answer (score 1):

full join probably works better than except in this case; this will cope with deletions and inserts too

```
 select coalesce(t1.emp_id, t2.emp_id),
 case when isnull(t1.dob,'')<>isnull(t2.dob,'')  then t2.dob else null end  DOB,
 case when isnull(t1.code,'')<>isnull(t2.code,'') then t2.code else null end  Code
 from table1 t1
 full join table2 t2 on t1.emp_id=t2.emp_id
 where isnull(t1.dob,'')<>isnull(t2.dob,'') or isnull(t1.code,'')<>isnull(t2.code,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

This data massage script will work in your case with sample data. You can tune it. The base idea is to find out what the different columns are.

```
with u as 
(   
    select emp_id, dob, code  from table1
    union
    select emp_id,  dob, code   from table2
),
d as 
(
    select emp_id, dob, code  from table1
    except
    select emp_id,  dob, code   from table2
),
c as
(
    select u.* from u inner join d
        on u.emp_id = d.emp_id and u.dob = d.dob            
    union
    select u.* from u inner join d
        on u.emp_id = d.emp_id and u.code = d.code
),
w as
(
    select c.emp_id, c.dob, c.code, 'CodeDiff' as Diff 
    from c inner join d
        on c.emp_id = d.emp_id and c.code <> d.code
            and c.dob = d.dob
    union 
    select c.emp_id, c.dob, c.code, 'DobDiff' as Diff 
    from c inner join d
        on c.emp_id = d.emp_id and c.code = d.code
            and c.dob <> d.dob
)
select 
    d.emp_id, 
    case w.Diff 
        when 'DobDiff' then cast(d.dob AS varchar(25))
        else ''
    end as dob,
    case w.Diff 
        when 'CodeDiff' then d.code
        else ''
    end as code
from d inner join w
    on d.emp_id = w.emp_id and d.code <> w.code
        and d.dob = w.dob
```